# -moz-box-flex does not work

Tags: css, flexbox

Why -moz-box-flex does not work in firefox?
Do i use an old syntax? I do need display -moz-box otherwise my whole layout doesn't work in firefox. It does work in chrome and safari. What's wrong?

```
.container{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
          -moz-box-direction: column;
width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.item{
    flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;       
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;

}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-box-flex It's a non-valid statement (or at least outdated). If you can reproduce the actual problem in a demo we can help/

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use vendor prefixes for flexbox in Firefox, unless you're coding for Firefox 27 or older. [Firefox 27 was released in February 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox#Version_27).

Since Firefox 28 (released March 2014) all flexbox properties have been supported without prefixes.

See flexbox browser support table: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox